# Mat-sort on a string of number ranges

Tags: typescript, sorting, angular-material

I'm trying to add sorting to my mat-table and so far it is working great.
However I'm currently struggling to sort my size column. The column contains strings like '1-5' and '6-20'. This is currently causing a lot of trouble.

I tried writing a sortingDataAccessor like this:

```js
              this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
                switch (property) {
                  case 'groupSize':
                    parseInt(
                      item.groupSize.substr(0, item.groupSize.indexOf('-')),
                      10
                    );
                    break;
                  default:
                    return item[property];
                }
              };
```

But this also doesnt work. I really have no idea how I can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning in your `case 'groupSize'`. So it always returns `undefined`. Therefore it cannot sort. Try:

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
                switch (property) {
                  case 'groupSize':
                    return parseInt(
                      item.groupSize.substr(0, item.groupSize.indexOf('-')),
                      10
                    );
                  default:
                    return item[property];
                }
              };
```